# Delphi - How to Exclude/turn off all values in a set?

Tags: delphi, set

Delphi XE6 - I have a set.  I would like a simple way to turn ALL elements off.  i.e. instead of Exclude, something like ExcludeALL.  I have tried to loop through all elements, but I get an error.

Code

```
 type
      TSearchParametersType = 
       (smDUNSAvailable = 1, 
        smDUNSHit,    
        smDUNSMiss,    
        smDUNSAbsent, 
        smRegistryAvailable, 
        smRegistryHit, 
        smRegistryAbsent, 
        smRegistryMiss, 
        smNameAvailable, 
        smNameHitExact, 
        smNameHitWords, 
        smNameMiss  
    );

    // Now create a set type, where we can have a variable that has all the values of TSearchParametersType
    type
      TSearchParametersSet = set of TSearchParametersType;
 ...   

   var
   i : Integer;
   sSearchStatus: TSearchParametersSet;

    begin 
    for i :=  smDUNSAvailable to  smNameMiss do
      Exclude(sSearchStatus, i);
```

The error I get is "Incompatible Type:  'Integer' and TSearchParametersType.  "

Is there a simple way to Exclude ALL, other than MANUALLY going through every element?

Thanks

Comment: `sSearchStatus := [];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types#Sets):

> Every set type can hold the empty set, denoted by [].

So you can assign the empty set to your variable like this:

```
sSearchStatus := [];
```

FWIW, your code fails because `smDUNSAvailable` and `smNameMiss` are of type `TSearchParametersType` and so not compatible with the variable `i` which is of type `Integer`. In order to make your code work you would need to change the loop variable to be of type `TSearchParametersType`.

Comment: FWIW: in some languages (notably C and some derivates), it is possible to assign enumeration type values to integers, or vice versa. In Delphi -- or Object Pascal -- this is not possible. The types are strictly separate. I am pretty sure that @David knows this, but apparently not everyone does.

Comment: @Rudy, err, wait, like `I := Integer(enumValue);` and `T := TEnumType(I);` ?

Comment: @TLama Rudy means assignment without casts

Answer (score 3):

Let me start by saying that David's answer is the correct one.

I'll just post another one to show how you could do it manually. This code might come in handy some other time:

```
var
  sSearchStatus: TSearchParametersSet;
  SearchParametersType : TSearchParametersType;        
begin 
  sSearchStatus := [smDUNSHit, smDUNSMiss, smDUNSAbsent, smRegistryAvailable, smRegistryHit];

  for SearchParametersType :=  low(TSearchParametersType) to  high(TSearchParametersType) do
    Exclude(sSearchStatus, SearchParametersType);
end;
```